# Bubble sorting an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with a couple of simple user objects in it which contains information such as their ID, name, and password:

```
user1 = new User(19, "bsmith", "password");
user2 = new User(15, "jbrown", "password");
user3 = new User(23, "sgreen", "password");

userArray.add(person1);
userArray.add(person2);
userArray.add(person3);
```

I'm trying to sort them by their user ID using this bubble sort method I found:

```
public static void BubbleSort( int [ ] num )
{
 int j;
 boolean flag = true;   
 int temp;   

 while ( flag )
 {
        flag= false;    
        for( j=0;  j < num.length -1;  j++ )
        {
               if ( num[ j ] > num[j+1] )   
               {
                       temp = num[ j ];                
                       num[ j ] = num[ j+1 ];
                       num[ j+1 ] = temp;
                      flag = true;              
              }
        }
  }
}
```

I just have no idea how to actually use it on my ArrayList. I managed to get it to sort a regular array though:

```
int j[] = {10,30,20,50};

People p = new People();

p.BubbleSort(j);

for (int i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(j[i]);
}
```

My question: Is it possible to use the bubble sort directly on the ID of each user in my ArrayList, or do I have to somehow put each users's ID into another array and use the bubble sort method on that?

Comment: what's wrong with  Collections.sort(arrayList); ??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: Why do you specially want to implement bubble sort when there is already a Collections.sort(list) method available?

Comment: for learning purpose maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you making a getID() method in the user class which returns the String ID.

```
private String id;
public String getID() {
    return id;
}
```

Then just call getID and sort the users by sorting the Strings

Answer (score 0):

The method you have found can be used on only for [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of int values: `int[]`, what you have is an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of `User` Objects: `ArrayList<User>`. So you need to do some changes to it in order to use it for your ArrayList.

First the signature, change

```
public static void BubbleSort( int [ ] num )
```

to

```
public static void BubbleSort( ArrayList<User> userList )
```

Then for accessing single elements you cannot use the index operator, you need to use the [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) and [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) methods of the ArrayList.

Sin the method is static, you don't have to create an instance to call it, just use the class name:

```
People.BubbleSort( userArray );
```

Finally Note that it is preferable to use an interface for declaring data types. So for ArrayList you could use the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) Interface line so:

```
List<User> userArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
public static void BubbleSort( List<User> userList )
```

Also please consider [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) for methods and variables, they should always start with lower-case letters.

```
public static void bubbleSort( List<User> userList )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can change your method to sort ArrayList of Integers

```
public static void BubbleSort( ArrayList<Integer> num )
{
    int j;
    boolean flag = true;
    int temp;

    while ( flag )
    {
        flag= false;
        for( j=0;  j < num.size() - 1;  j++ )
        {
            if ( num.get(j) > num.get(j+1) )
            {
                temp = num.get(j);
                num.set(j, num.get(j+1));
                num.set(j + 1, temp);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you need is to change it to compare by user.age, like

```
if ( num.get(j).getAge() > num.get(j+1).getAge() )
```

not sure what is the interface of User class